# Logger is printing the message twice and some times even more for the whole program

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jboss, log4j

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(filename.class);

logger.debug("logger" + element);
```

this line is printing twice and some times more..

this prints as

```
logger 123
logger 123
```

(on different lines)

Comment: Would you allow a peek into your log4java.conf (or log4j.properties or log4j.xml)?

Comment: yep, I am using log4j, but the logger is working fine for other files , except for this and logger is enabled to debug

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if multiple loggers are qualifying for this class (where the appender configured for these qualifying loggers should be similar) and each one is printing the message.

A look at your log4j configuration file would help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was i was calling the configure file twice it has fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration()
```

after *BasicConfigurator.configure()* in the method that uses logger